# How to add new column with conditional values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to add a new column with values which is conditional also. And Getting below error -

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Add Column SQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Dbo'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'User'
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'CanEdit')
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [User]
        ADD CanEdit
        AS
        (CASE WHEN IdUser IN (SELECT u.IdUser 
                            FROM [User] u INNER JOIN UserRole Usrl
                            ON u.IdUser = Usrl.IdUser INNER JOIN [Role] Rl
                            ON Usrl.IdRole = Rl.IdRole AND Rl.[Name] = 'Admin') THEN 1
                                                                                           
                                                                                 ELSE 0
         END)
    END
```

Comment: You can't use subqueries on a computed column, as the error says. Use a `VIEW` and `JOIN` to the table.

Comment: You *can* use a scalar function in a computed column and put your query in the function (I would use an *exists* and no need to touch the [user] table a second time), whether you *should* depends, doing so has its own caveats; creating a view on top of the table is probably the better decision.

Comment: I think it's simpler to use a two-step rocket: 1) ADD column first 2) Update column by a join or whatever.